# Blink.jl and Vue/Vite setup

Tags: vue.js, julia

I set up a barebones Vue/Vite project and pointed Blink.jl at the local Vite dev server like this:

```
using Blink

w = Window(async=false)
loadurl(w, "http://localhost:9100/")
opentools(w)

while true
    sleep(1)
end
```

But the window doesn't load the main.ts file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">hello</div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting this in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
    at overlay.ts:140
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your head tag and enable legacy polyfills.

```
<script>
  if (globalThis === undefined) {
    var globalThis = window;
  }
</script>
```